# Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance

Tags: android, adb

I get that warning on the cmd when i try to execute this activity.

I'm new here using adb so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. Any advice?

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings$MobileNetworkListActivity

Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance
```

Answer (score 3):

The command `am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings$MobileNetworkListActivity` is interpreted by Android like this:

1. Start the app `com.android.settings`
2. Open the activity `com.android.settings.Settings$MobileNetworkListActivity`

Now you got the message

`Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance`

This effectively means that an instance of the app `com.android.settings` was already running in foreground (top-most) when you executed the  `am start` command. And Android was just telling you that instead of starting a new instance of the Android settings app it had reused the already open instance and had sent the intent that contains the information to open the activity `com.android.settings.Settings$MobileNetworkListActivity` to that instance.

So everything is fine, the command was successfully executed, you can simply ignore this warning.

Comment: if intent is delivered again, why don't reach my breakpoints so?

Comment: if com.android.settings.Settings$MobileNetworkListActivity is not the top activity when run the command, it seems not deliver the intent to the top activity at that time (maybe activityA or activityB in my case). How I force app to open MobileNetworkListActivity again (in my case, its name is different ?

Comment: I posted question if you can help please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77836735/how-to-force-android-to-open-the-activity-that-registered-as-the-deeplink-in-man