# How to force android to open the activity that registered as the deeplink in manifest in second call?

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I have the registered below activity in `AndroidManifest` for being opened when I run deeplink

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestDeeplink">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="testdeeplink" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

After the above activity is opened, it will navigate to below activity when user tap on the test button

```
        <activity
        android:name=".DashboardActivity"
        android:label="DashboardActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestDeeplink"/>
```

I test with command line and it show like below logs

First time:

```
adb shell am start -d testdeeplink://test
Starting: Intent { dat=testdeeplink://test }
```

Second time:

```
adb shell am start -d testdeeplink://test
Starting: Intent { dat=testdeeplink://test }
Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance.
```

If app has already navigated to `DashboardActivity`, its `onNewIntent` method is not called
Otherwise app stay at `MainActivity`, its `onNewIntent` method is called with expected value

How to force app to open `MainActivity` every time the deeplink is called ?

`Updated`: I changed `launchMode` of `MainActivity` from `singleTop` to `singleTask` or `singleInstance`. The behaviosr is ok, anyone helps me to explain more detail about this ?